# Backtracking prorblem and I don't know if my plan to solve it is correct

Tags: java, recursive-backtracking

I am practicing a backtracking problem and here is the problem description:
https://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem/view/cs2/sections/recursivebacktracking/travel

Write a method travel that accepts integers x and y as parameters and uses recursive backtracking to print all solutions for traveling in the 2-D plane from (0, 0) to (x, y) by repeatedly using one of three moves:

East (E): move right 1 (increase x)
North (N): move up 1 (increase y)
Northeast (NE): move up 1 and right 1 (increase both x and y).

Here is what I got:
I get it to work on one path but I am not sure how to make it go explore all other possible paths. I am thinking my base case design is wrong but I am not sure. I just want to know what I should fix first, is the base case or my entire concept is wrong.

```
public class PracticeRecordCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        travel(1, 2);
    }
    public static String travel(int x, int y){
        List<String> allpath = new ArrayList<String>();

        String eachpath = "";

        return explore(0, 0, x, y, eachpath, allpath);
    }

    public static String explore(int x, int y, int des_x, int dest_y, String eachPath, List<String> allpath) {
        //Base case
        if(x == des_x && y== dest_y) {
                String result = "";
                if(isRepeated(eachPath, allpath)){
                    allpath.add(eachPath);
                    eachPath = "";
                }
            // Print all content from allpath
                for (String path : allpath) {
                    result += path + "\n";
                    System.out.println(path);
                }
                return result;
        } else {

            if(x == des_x && y != dest_y){
                eachPath += "N ";
                if(!allpath.contains(eachPath)) {
                    allpath.add(eachPath);
                }
                explore(x, y+1, des_x, dest_y, eachPath, allpath);
            } else if(x != des_x && y == dest_y) {
                eachPath += "E ";
                allpath.add(eachPath);
                explore(x + 1, y, des_x, dest_y, eachPath, allpath);
            } else {
                eachPath += "NE ";
                allpath.add(eachPath);
                explore(x + 1, y+1, des_x, dest_y, eachPath, allpath);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Check if this path has been done already
    public static boolean isRepeated(String path, List<String> allpath){
        return allpath.contains(path);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can do some improvements to your `explore` method, as there is some defect in your implementation. There are two exit conditions: 1. when you reach the destination, which is a valid path and we can save it into your final result. 2. you reach over the destination `(x>des_x || y>dest_y)`, which means that's an invalid path, and we don't have to keep exploring any more. And otherwise, you have 3 options to keep exploring: E, N, or NE. And as each direction is unique, you don't have to worry about duplicate.
when all possible explore is done, your `allpath` list will have all the valid paths added. And you can either return the list or print it.
Based on this, your code can be much simpler like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PracticeRecordCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        travel(2, 2);
    }
    public static void travel(int x, int y){
        List<String> allpath = new ArrayList<String>();

        explore(0, 0, x, y, "", allpath);

        // Print all content from allpath
        for (String path : allpath) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }

    }

    public static void explore(int x, int y, int des_x, int dest_y, String eachPath, List<String> allpath) {
        //Base case
        if(x == des_x && y == dest_y) {
            allpath.add(eachPath);
            return;
        }
        if(x>des_x || y>dest_y)
            return;
        explore(x + 1, y, des_x, dest_y, eachPath + "E ", allpath);

        explore(x, y+1, des_x, dest_y, eachPath + "N ", allpath);

        explore(x + 1, y+1, des_x, dest_y, eachPath + "NE ", allpath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think what confused me the most is the part of I put all explore recursions at if-else statements and I did not change my eachPath during each recursion so it wouldn't update itself.

Comment: Plus I did screw up the base case, there are supposed to be at least two conditions. I think that's the main reason why I couldn't understand it earlier.

Comment: Yes, your if-else statements logic is not correct: if(x == des_x && y != dest_y), which means it only moves 'E'ast when x == des_x, but actually, it can moves when x<des_x.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code. Hope it may give your solution->

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    baktracking(new boolean[5][3], 0, 0, 2, 2, "");
}

static void baktracking(boolean m[][], int x, int y, int dx, int dy, String ans) {
    if (x == dx && y == dy) {
        System.out.println(ans);
        return;
    }
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= m.length || y >= m[0].length) {
        return;
    }
    m[x][y] = true;
    baktracking(m, x, y +1, dx, dy, ans + "E" + " ");
    baktracking(m, x + 1, y, dx, dy, ans + "N" + " ");
    baktracking(m, x + 1, y + 1, dx, dy, ans + "NE" + " ");
    m[x][y] = false;
}
```

Comment: I think it is better if I know how to improve it but I appreciate the code, I can get some idea from that.